# Dask having problems with read_sql_table

Tags: python, dask

I want to use Dask for some SQL large table, but when I run

```
dd.read_sql_table('ORDENES', str(engine.url), index_col='ID', npartitions=1)
```

I receive this

```
TypeError: Additional arguments should be named <dialectname>_<argument>, got 'autoload'
```

The original engine is this:

```
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://" + "xxx" + ":" + "xxx" + "@" + "xxx.amazonaws.com" + "/" + "facturacion")
```

Any Idea of how to fix this?, I tried to add autoload to mysql engine, but the driver do not accept that

Comment: Do you have a more complete exception stack trace?
Are you able to read data with sqlalchemy only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dask uses SQLAlchemy to perform SQL operations. The problem is that currently dask hasn't been updated to work with SQLAlchemy 2.0.

It still uses the `autoload` argument when [creating an SQLAlchemy Table](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/main/dask/dataframe/io/sql.py#L302) object.

According to the [SQLAlchemy migration to 2.0 guide](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/migration_20.html) `autoload_with=engine` should be used instead.

Until dask is updated to support SQLAlchemy 2.0, the easiest workaround is to use SQLAlchemy version 1.4.45.

`pip install sqlalchemy==1.4.45`